# Interactions in Propensity Score Models

Tags: interaction, propensity-scores, treatment-effect

I am doing an analysis to see if a first-year seminar has an effect on student retention in college. Students choose whether or not to enroll in the seminar on their own, so it seems like it makes sense to use a propensity score model to properly account for the covariates that affect whether or not a student enrolls in the seminar.

However, in doing an exploratory analysis of the data, it appears there is an interaction between seminar participation and student aptitude; the seminar has a more positive effect on retention for more apt students than less apt ones. My question: Is it possible to incorporate a treatment interaction in a propensity score model? Or am I forced to use another method if I want to test an interaction like the one I've mentioned?

Comment: Hi, What is the methods that you are using to come up with propensity score probabilisties ?

Comment: How are you using the propensity scores? Are you matching on them or using them as a covariate?

Comment: I have many more non-treatment subjects than treatment subjects (~600 vs. ~200), so I'm planning to use the scores as a covariate so I don't lose ~400 subjects due to matching. As for how I plan on calculating the scores, I haven't gotten that far yet. Logistic regression would be a simple way, but I have experience with more advanced classification methods, and I'm open to using any of those.

Comment: I don't recommend the use of matching when it discards any observations.  Also please state why ordinary covariate adjustment doesn't work in your case.  Propensity score analysis (preferably through covariate adjustment by a nonlinear function of the logit propensity after checking non-overlap regions) is usually reserved for the case when the number of potential confounders is too great for their coefficients against $Y$ to be reliably estimated.

Comment: Good question, Frank. One reason I was leaning toward using a propensity score model is because the results will likely be shown/read by a non-technical audience of higher education administrators. Most administrators I talk to seem to be more familiar with cohort matching (either one-to-one, or one-to many) designs. Are a multiple regression and propensity score model with a treatment indicator variable statistically equivalent? I imagine they have other differences than just interpretation ease.

Comment: I commonly model the interaction between treatment and a spline function in the logit propensity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referred to as treatment effect heterogeneity (e.g. see [Angrist 2004](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.0013-0133.2003.00195.x/full)). There are methods that combine propensity score adjustment with outcome models to reveal interaction effects as such, for example see "Facilitating Score and Causal Inference Trees for Large Observational Studies" ([Su et al. 2012](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2503336)).